# How to use drawable resource file with glide to animate my icon?

Tags: android, animation, android-glide

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/loadingicon"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"></animated-rotate>
```

This is my drawable file. I am trying to use it with Glide to animate my loading icon.